# How to read size and move hidden element before Vue transition starts on it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-transitions, vuejs2

How to read dimensions and move a div that is hidden before Vue transition starts? For example, a user clicks a button and I want to move a hidden div to appear under the button with a fade-in transition. I need to be able to both read the dimensions and move the top/left position of the hidden div before the transition starts.

Let's say I'm using `v-show="active"` on the div, where `active` is my reactive data property I want to set to true and be able to move the div before transition starts.

I've tried all these:

- Move the div first, then on nextTick set active = true.
- Use the javascript hook beforeEnter to try to move the div before transitions start.
- Use the javascript hook enter (and 'done' callback) to try to move the div before transition starts.
- Tried all the above with updating the DOM immediately with the new position before setting active = true. (In other words, not via data binding, but actually setting element style properties directly like `this.$refs.content.style.top = '500px'` to avoid any waiting on the virtual DOM.) However, ideally I would like to accomplish this without directly touching the DOM, but using nextTicks instead. Both approaches fail.
- Tried with some success with a hacky `transition: all .8ms ease-in, top 1ms, left 1ms`.
- Tried with success with moving the div first then setting active in a setTimeout. This is not the right solution though.

**Update**
Thanks to the accepted answer I was able to see that I can read dimensions on nextTick (by which time v-show has turned on display). However, it turns out I needed the transition to be all `transition all .3s` and that would cause the movement to be included. The DOM will gather up all the changes and apply them together, which means they get lumped into the transition that is later added by Vue. The solution ended up being that I needed to make the movements, then trigger the DOM to repaint first, then trigger the v-show to turn on. Here's an example method:

```
startTransition () {
  this.$refs.content.offsetHeight // <-- Force DOM to repaint first.
  this.isContentActive = true     // <-- Turns on v-show.
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`v-bind:style`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1) to move your window and it all works as intended.

**Update**: To check the size of the popup itself, it has to be shown, so I'm using `v-show` instead of `v-if`. The first thing I do is make it visible; on the next tick, I can measure it and place it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data: {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 0,
    show: false
  },
  methods: {
    showFloater: function(evt) {
      const t = evt.target;

      this.show = true;
      Vue.nextTick(() => {
        const fEl = this.$el.querySelector('.floating');

        this.top = t.offsetTop + 30;
        this.left = t.offsetLeft;
        this.width = fEl.offsetWidth;
        setTimeout(() => this.show = false, 1000);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.floating {
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: 3em;
  position: absolute;
}

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active in <2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button @click="showFloater">Could go here</button>
  <button @click="showFloater">Or here</button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <div v-show="show" class="floating" v-bind:style="{
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px'
    }">
      This window is {{width}}px wide.
    </div>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: One thing I notice here is you aren't reading div size (like height) as I mentioned in the question. However I'll still try your answer in just a little later this afternoon when I get to my pc. If it works perhaps the breaking happens when trying to read div size before transition. Can you update your code for this and try it?

Comment: @prograhammer What div size should I be reading? I'm getting the offsetTop of the buttons to choose the popup's position. The popup itself is not part of the DOM at click-time due to the `v-if`, so it has no size.

Comment: Exactly. You'll need to unhide the popup briefly to get size and this is most likely the source of the transition malfunctioning. Imagine you need to determine if that popup goes off screen by reading its height or width (real use case) so you can flip it other direction. For example purposes just console.log the height. But I'm certain your transition will now break.

Comment: Doesn't work. The transition starts and you see the div slowly move into the new position and fade in at the same time. I'll make a codepen tonight to show you. Did you try the code yourself that you posted? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually nevermind, I created a codepen and it works. Same approach just not working in my own code. Let me check a little more then I think I can accept your answer.

Comment: Sounds like you may have some DOM-manipulating code still in place that is fighting with Vue's manipulation of the DOM.

Comment: Accepting your answer now, thank you for helping point this out. I had some extra stuff in my styles that may have been the culprit, stripped it down and it works, so I'll sniff it out tonight and report back. For a bonus +1, any idea why the width is read slightly off on first attempt? Here's the codepen I made: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpGGjj based on your example. Notice when you click the button1 and then hide and then click button2 the width has changed. Weird???

Comment: Ok, so apparently I need to create a new question. This answer partially addresses the issue but if you take opacity away from the transition line, and use all: `transition: 1.5s` then you can see the transition picks up the top/left moves. See updated codepen.

Comment: The width of the floater changes when it populates its own text with its width.

Comment: If you set `transition: 1.5s`, it is going to transition the positioning as well as the opacity. You don't want it to do that, but that's what you're telling it to do.

Comment: Yeah, but that was the goal to be able to do stuff before transition is added. If you look at Vue source, it calls next animation frame, with no chance to get in anything beforehand. I figured a solution though, by doing the moving, then forcing the DOM to repaint, then turning on v-show.

Comment: If you don't want to see things move, don't put transitions on things moving. You're not "doing stuff before transition is added", you're moving (slowly) the div while it's invisible, then making it visible. Only put transitions on things you want to transition. Then you won't have to hide the transitioning.

Comment: That's just it, I didn't put the transition on during the time I was moving the element. But the browser decides to wait and not repaint so it gets caught in the transition Vue adds afterwards. Also, I think there are many use cases where someone would want to move an element to a certain place (with no transition) and once it's there then you want further movement to be included in a transition. Vue offers a beforeEnter Javascript hook. I think that suggests there is reason to do stuff before transition IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your help Roy, your answer address my problem and helped me solve the last bits I needed too. See my updated question (to help anyone else stumbling across this issue).